# R error for custom package with S4 classes: class "classname" has a locked definition in package "pkgname"

Tags: r, class, oop, package, r-s4

I created a package containing the following function:

```
make_LD <- function(a) {
  setClass("LongitudinalData", slots = list(subject = "numeric", visit = "numeric", room = "character", timepoint = "numeric", value = "numeric"))
  new("LongitudinalData", subject = a$id, visit = a$visit, room = a$room, timepoint = a$timepoint, value = a$value)
}
```

`make_LD` works fine in a workspace where it is explicitly defined, but not when I call the function elsewhere after loading the package.  When I do this, I get the error:

```
Error in assignClassDef(Class, classDef, where) : class "LongitudinalData" has a locked definition in pkgname'
```

Could someone explain how I should have gone about defining an S4 class in the package such that data from elsewhere can be used to instantiate a new object of that class?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `make_LD` attempts to redefine the class `"LongitudinalData"` every time it is called (that's what `setClass` does.) Thus, when the user calls it, R refuses to redefine the class because it would conflict with the definition that already exists, if any.

Most likely, you want to have the `setClass` statement as a standalone somewhere in your package. Then, your function `make_LD` just calls `new` and returns the result.